# Dynamically Parse Child Nodes in JSON

Tags: json.net

I have a deserialized object that I want to dynamically loop through to return the related results. The response package looks like so:

```
{"RatingResponse":
 {"Success":"true",
  "Message":"",
  "QuoteID":"57451",
  "LoadNum":"57451",
  "Rates":
    {"Rate":
        [
            {"SCAC":"test1",
             "CarrierName":"TEST1",
             "TransitTime":"1",
             "ServiceLevel":"D",
             "TotalCost":"1,031.82",
             "ThirdPartyCharge":"1,031.82",
             "Accessorials":
                {"Accessorial":
                    [
                        {"Code":"400",
                        "Cost":"1,655.55",
                        "Description":"Freight"
                        },
                        
                        {"Code":"DSC",
                        "Cost":"-952.77",
                        "Description":"Discount"
                        },
                        
                        {"Code":"FUE",
                        "Cost":"329.04",
                        "Description":"Fuel Surcharge"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "QuoteNumber":""
            },
            
            {"SCAC":"test2",
            "CarrierName":"TEST2",
            "TransitTime":"1",
            "ServiceLevel":"D",
            "TotalCost":"1,031.82",
            "ThirdPartyCharge":"1,031.82",
            "Accessorials":
                {"Accessorial":
                    [
                        {"Code":"400",
                        "Cost":"1,655.55",
                        "Description":"Freight"
                        },
                        
                        {"Code":"DSC",
                        "Cost":"-952.77",
                        "Description":"Discount"
                        },
                        
                        {"Code":"FUE",
                        "Cost":"329.04",
                        "Description":"Fuel Surcharge"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "QuoteNumber":""
            }
        ]
    },
    "AverageTotalCost":"1,031.82"
   }
 }
```

I have parsed the response data so that there is less information to work with, especially since I only need the Accessorial Costs. The parsed response looks like

```
 [
 {
"SCAC": "test1",
"CarrierName": "TEST1",
"TransitTime": "1",
"ServiceLevel": "D",
"TotalCost": "1,031.82",
"ThirdPartyCharge": "1,031.82",
"Accessorials": {
  "Accessorial": [
    {
      "Code": "400",
      "Cost": "1,655.55",
      "Description": "Freight"
    },
    {
      "Code": "DSC",
      "Cost": "-952.77",
      "Description": "Discount"
    },
    {
      "Code": "FUE",
      "Cost": "329.04",
      "Description": "Fuel Surcharge"
    }
  ]
},
"QuoteNumber": ""
 },
 {
"SCAC": "test2",
"CarrierName": "TEST2",
"TransitTime": "1",
"ServiceLevel": "D",
"TotalCost": "1,031.82",
"ThirdPartyCharge": "1,031.82",
"Accessorials": {
  "Accessorial": [
    {
      "Code": "400",
      "Cost": "1,655.55",
      "Description": "Freight"
    },
    {
      "Code": "DSC",
      "Cost": "-952.77",
      "Description": "Discount"
    },
    {
      "Code": "FUE",
      "Cost": "329.04",
      "Description": "Fuel Surcharge"
    }
  ]
},
"QuoteNumber": ""
}
]
```

The problem I am facing is that I will never know how many Rate items will come back in the response data, nor will I know the exact amount of Accessorial Costs. I'm hoping to capture the Rate child node counts and the Accessorial child node counts per Rate. Here's what I have so far.

```
   Root rootObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(responseFromServer);
   //rate stores the parsed response data
   JArray rate = (JArray)JObject.Parse(responseFromServer)["RatingResponse"]["Rates"]["Rate"];
   var rate2 = rate.ToString();

   //this for loop works as expected. it grabs the number of Rate nodes (in this example, 2)
   for (int i = 0; i < rate.Count(); i++)
       {
          dynamic test2 = rate[i];
          //this is where I'm struggling
          dynamic em = (JArray)JObject.Parse(test2)["Accessorials"]["Accessorial"].Count();
             for (int j = 0; j < em; j++)
                 {
                    string test3 = test2.Accessorials.Accessorial[j].Cost;
                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logPath, Environment.NewLine + test3 + Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                }
```

I apologize in advance for the bad formatting and odd variable names - I'm obviously still testing the functionality, so I've been using random variables.

Where I'm struggling (as notated above) is getting to the Accessorial node to count how many items are in its array. I was thinking I could parse the first array (starting with SCAC data) and extend down to the Accessorial node, but I'm not having any luck.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated, especially since I am new to this type of code and have spent the majority of the day trying to resolve this.

Comment: You have to post the final json or result you want. Do you need just list of costs or some more information?

Comment: I just need a list of summarized costs. Instead of using the total cost field, I'd like to just do a summation on the absolute value of the costs so that the discount isn't taken into affect.

Comment: I still don't understand what do you want. Just one number - sum of all costs  or cost should be grouped by something?

Comment: Sum of accessorial costs (abs value) per carrier name. It should display something like "TEST1 : 2937.36 \n TEST2 : 2937.36." I'm just not sure how to find the number of child nodes under the Accessorials\Accessorial node.

Comment: But it will be the same sum as TotalCost

Comment: Not in this case because the discount is a negative value. If you add all of the accessorials without taking an absolute value, you'll get the listed TotalCost. I want to ignore the discount.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var rates = (JArray)JObject.Parse(json)["RatingResponse"]["Rates"]["Rate"];
var costs = rates.Select(r => new
    {
        CarrierName = r["CarrierName"],
        Costs = ((JArray)((JObject)r["Accessorials"])["Accessorial"])
                            .Where(r => (string)r["Description"] != "Discount")
                            .Select(r => (double)r["Cost"]).Sum()
    }).ToList();
```

result

```
[
  {
    "CarrierName": "TEST1",
    "Costs": 1984.59
  },
  {
    "CarrierName": "TEST2",
    "Costs": 1984.59
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Is this a LINQ statement? For whatever reason, it's complaining about the "r" value not being declared. I'm using Newstonsoft.Json.Linq, so I would assume it would work.

Comment: @user2572833q Yes, it is a linq. It is working at my machine. r doesn't mean anything, you can select any another letter or the whole word.

Comment: I greatly appreciate all of your help! The issue it has with the r value is "A local or parameter named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter" but I don't have that variable defined anywhere else. Any idea why it doesn't like it?

Comment: @user2572833 Just copy paste code and thats it.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Do I need a reference to anything other than Newtonsoft.Json.Linq?

Comment: @user2572833 maybe just system.linq

Comment: Got that one as well.